# Media queries and meta viewport not working correctly

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I am practicing responsive design with this jsbin project: http://jsbin.com/edELane/4

If you resize the window on the desktop, the functionality is there, but I can't replicate it on an actual mobile device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: No luck, it doesn't look like initial scale is working. I am testing on iPhone 5.

Comment: What device were you on?

Comment: May be you need to check browser's settings on your device? Look at this cite, your site lokks norm: http://www.responsivedesigntest.net/

Comment: And i use "web developer tools" with Firefox. P.S. Sorry, my english so bad now )))